# How to check if a parameter passed is the type of my interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes an object now this object's shape can be of one of three interfaces:

```
interface A{
strig:string
}
interface B{
number:number
}
interface C{
boolean:boolean
}
```

The function takes this object an does different things depending on the shape of the object I want to do something like this

```
function doSomething(item: object){
if(item typeof A) do A effecst;
if(item typeof B) do B effect;
if(item typeof B) do C effect;
}
```

But I get the error  "'IComic' only refers to a type, but here it is used as a value."

Comment: [Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: i tried this if(item is A) but i still get the error  "'IComic' only refers to a type, but here it is used as a value."  IComic is one of my interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this out for only A first. We have the interface here:

```
interface A {
    string: string;
}
```

and now to check it, we have to use something similar to `typeof value.string === "string"`. Let's return that from a function:

```
function isA(value: any) {
    // check if value is truthy first
    return value && typeof value.string === "string";
}
```

Then we just use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isA(value: any): value is A {
```

You'll now be able to use it to narrow a value in an if statement (or any condition):

```
if (isA(aOrBOrC)) {
    aOrBOrC // is now type A
}
```

Comment: the problem i have is im trying to do this inside a reducer swicht stament and each interface has many properties